# ASP.NET application moving from webforms to routes, best way to redirect URLs?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm updating our web app to use routes rather then the webform page name. What is the best way to handle redirecting all of the old addresses to new ones?

I'm mostly concerned about web spiders, etc. Is it possible to when a certain page is requested to return a 302 header and redirect?

Is there a simple way to manage this all from one location?

Answer (score 1):

if it were me, i would create an IIS redirect to an ASPX redirect. Meaning that i would redirect all the old adresses to a specific page, and that page would then read the original address header and, based on which one, create a Routing call with the proper parameters, which would by nature redirect the user to the proper page.

Comment: What would be the advantage to doing it like that versus register a routing table in the application such as "old routes" and just create routes that map the old requests to the correct pages. This would make it easier to maintain, correct? Any downside to doing it this way?

Comment: Uhm... yeah that's a good one as well. The only thing, which applies to both, is that you don't have to change any existing links. But both are proper and valid! :-)

Comment: Is there any SEO advantage to doing it in IIS? If i do it via a routing table it is possible to send a redirect tag ex 301 in the header?

Comment: In my.mind they are both the same. Both require a fair amount of work and both offer the same options... e.g.: anything related to this can be done in code, or in IIS... So it's your choice really...